# Get the latest PostgreSQL version available in a region

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Is there any gcloud cli command or api call that I can use to see the  latest/newest available PostgreSQL versions in region?

I found [db-versions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/db-versions) page, but I need to check which is the latest/newest available version programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no a direct way to know this using `gcloud` CLI but I think the best (and awful) approach will be usign the `help` flag. Here are three versions so you can choose the one that could help you.

**Version 1:**

```
$ gcloud sql instances create --help | egrep -o '(MYSQL|POSTGRES)\w*'
MYSQL_5_5
MYSQL_5_6
MYSQL_5_7
POSTGRES_9_6
POSTGRES_11
```

**Version 2:**

```
$ gcloud sql instances create --help | egrep -o 'POSTGRES\w*'
POSTGRES_9_6
POSTGRES_11
```

**Version 3:**

```
$ gcloud sql instances create --help | egrep -o 'POSTGRES\w*' | egrep -o '_\w*' | sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/_/./'
9.6
11
```

This versions will work assuming `gcloud` help is always updated.